# oracle order by default type desc or asc 11g vs 10g

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, oracle11g, sql-order-by

Are there any differences in the default sort type of the `ORDER BY` clause in oracle?

I know it is `ASC` if I ommit putting `DESC` immediately after order in 10 g.

Is it the same for 11g?

Comment: Default is `ASC` in all SQL products.

Comment: Hey, don't hit. That is a valid question. Working with SQL since 20 years this seems a bit a too basic questions, but I don't see why this is -2 here.

Comment: thank you hol, I complletely agree with you...

Comment: Basic but valid question, why was it downvoted ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the documentation.

It says:

**ASC | DESC Specify the ordering sequence (ascending or descending). ASC is the default.**

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions001.htm

Answer (score 0):

yes it is same for 11g also.

when you not specify any ordering clause then the default is ASC . if you want to override this default behavior then explicitly mention desc .